# Carbon Php timer (step counter) returns NaN only iPhone

Tags: javascript, php, date, php-carbon

I have a problem with Carbon PHP. I receive a `date` from Backend and make a step counter. But the `step counter` works fine on computers and android. But on iPhone, it gives `Nan`. How can I solve this?

```
      <script>
            var c = new Date('{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $productOfDay->expired_at) }}').getTime();
            console.log(c); // iPhone returns NaN here

            var mf = setInterval(function() {
                var n = new Date().getTime();
                var t = c - n;
                var da = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                var ho = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));

                var mins = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                var sec = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
                document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = da;
                document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = ho;
                if (ho < 10) {
                    document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = "0" + ho;
                }
                document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML = mins;
                if (mins < 10) {
                    document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML = "0" + mins;
                }
                document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML = sec;
                if (sec < 10) {
                    document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML = "0" + sec;
                }
                if (t < 0) {
                    clearInterval(mf);
                    document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = "";
                    document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = "";
                    document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML = "";
                    document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML = "";
                    document.getElementById("end").innerHTML = "TIMES UP Please try new dates!!";
                }   
       }, 1000);
  </script>
```

Comment: In `'Y-m-d H:i:s'`, put a "T" between the date and time parts to create a format supported by ECMA-262 (and therefore all compliant implementations). E.g. `"2022-09-14T15:23:15"` should be reliably parsed as local. If you want it parsed as UTC, append a "Z".

Comment: So for UTC, use `'Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z'`.

Comment: @RobG Yeah, I know about "T" in JS not PHP. And now I tried ```'Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z```, after your comment. But I got the error ```Unexpected data found. Data missing```.  My code ```{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', $productOfDay->expired_at) }}```

Comment: It seems you're using PHP tokens but perhaps quoting literals is not supported in your environment? Anyway, if you can generate a compliant string then you won't have any issues. The "T" isn't javascript, it's specified by ISO 8601, ECMAScript just supports that ISO 8601 format.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I deleted `carbon` and use `json_encode`.

```
            const product = (<?= json_encode($productOfDay) ?>);
            var b = new Date(product.expired_at).getTime();
```